Закругление углов в выемке внутри блока
Как лучше сделать скругление углов у этой выемки?
Вот так должно быть

А вот так у меня

Вот мой код
      const BigBlock = styled.div`
        border-radius: 30px;
        background: rgb(248, 237, 227);
        width: 650px;
        height: 430px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 60.5% 0%, 64.63% 10.46%, 76.15% 10.46%, 81% 0%, 100% 0.75%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);

